# Error when performing site search after 2013 upgrade

Tags: 2013, search-results, upgrade

I just upgraded our farm from SharePoint 2010 to 2013, attaching the content databases to the new farm instance. However, we've decided to leave all the sites in the 2010 visual model until we can further train users on the differences.

Most of our content is working well. However, whenever a search is attempted at the site level in a 2010 visual style, we receive the following error:

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open
>   this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server administrator.
>
> Correlation ID:6474799c-e8bf-80ef-0089-f1547f35a6db
>
> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open
>   this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server administrator.

Pulling up the ULS logs with that correlation ID gives me the following relevant errors:

> Error while executing web part: System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException: XSLT
>   compile error. An error occurred  at (0,0). --->
>   System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.      at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String res)      at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()      at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltInput.ReadNextSibling()      at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltInput.FindStylesheetElement()      at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadDocument()      at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadStylesheet(XmlReader reader,
>   Boolean include)     -  -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadStylesheet(XmlReader reader,
>   Boolean include)      at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.Load(Compiler
>   compiler, Object stylesheet, XmlResolver xmlResolver)      at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.Compiler.Compile(Object stylesheet, XmlResolver
>   xmlResolver, QilExpression& qil)      at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.LoadInternal(Object stylesheet,
>   XsltSettings settings, XmlResolver stylesheetResolver)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.LoadXslCompiledTransform(WSSXmlUrlResolver
>   someXmlResolver)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXslCompiledTransform()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean
>   bDeferExecuteTransform)
>
> InnerException 1: System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String res)
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()      at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltInput.ReadNextSibling()      at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltInput.FindStylesheetElement()      at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadDocument()      at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadStylesheet(XmlReader reader,
>   Boolean include)

Has anyone run into this when performing an update, and have any clue how it might be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow up for everyone, in case they run into this issue.
I opened up a case with Microsoft support. One of the first things the technician had me do was a SELECT * on the dbo.MSSLocations database in the Search Service Application admin database. No results were present, while there are 5 rows expected.

With that information, the technician had me execute the followin PS commands:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "My Search Service App"
$ssa.Status = "Disabled"
$ssa.Update()
$ssa.Provision()
```

It didn't work right away, but when I came back to it in the morning, my searches were now completing successfully.

Comment: Yes!!! I had to recreate the search app because my usage reports weren't working. When I did, it broke search on two of our web apps that were still in 2010 (UI) mode. I check the MSSLocations database and it was empty. I ran the script and results started showing up. Thanks!